# Axis 1.4 : An error occurred when verifying security for the message

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

I generated axis 1.4 web service client using Eclipse and when trying to consume one of the services, I get the error:

> An error occurred when verifying security for the message

I tried sending the username & password in stub header as follows:

```
            String userNameStr="myusername";
            String passwordStr="mypassword";
            String namespace = "http://mynamespace.org/";
            org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement header = new org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement(namespace,"AuthHeader");
            SOAPElement node = header.addChildElement("Username");
            node.addTextNode(userNameStr);
            SOAPElement node2 = header.addChildElement("Password");
            node2.addTextNode(passwordStr); 

            _stub.setHeader(header);
```

but still keep getting same error. How can I fix this error?